# Only last added jquery script works

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7

I`ve added 2 custom jquery scripts in my theme template.php function mythemename_preprocess_html(&$variables) using

```
drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() . '/js/to-top.js');
drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() . '/js/flashbutton.js');
```

But only one last added works. When I change places works another.

if I insert first code into second and saving in one file it works.

Adding scripts in mytheme.info file scripts[] = js/to-top.js doesn`t work.

Thanx for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleared! That`s my incompetence... I attached theme name to Drupal.behaviors (Drupal.behaviors.marketplace = {...)in both scripts instead of functionName (Drupal.behaviors.flashbut = {...), so for drupal it looks like one script, and worked only last in mytheme.info list. Thanks everyone for answers and helpful links...

Answer (score 0):

Try these....

1. You can add javascript on .info

scripts[] = javascript.js

2.Add javascript on template.php

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'nameofthetheme') . '/js/jquery');
```

3.For exrenal javascripts

```
drupal_add_js('http://sitename.com/javascript.js', 'external'));
```

4.You may also use it in page.tpl.php  use

```
<? php print drupal_get_js(); ?>.
```

Hope this might help....

Comment: Tanx for answer @Outlooker.

Comment: But as I`ve said above scripts[]=javascript.js doesn`t work at all. Methods 2, 3, 4 you`ve mentioned are working, but pay attention there 2 scripts - AND WORKS ONLY ONE LAST ADDED

Answer (score 0):

Conflicts between java script might cause some of them to be removed or neglected.The JavaScript that you need to be loaded on all pages can be added into the theme's .info file. Just roll on to the following link..its quite useful..

http://drupal.org/node/171205#scripts.

The drupal community itself has given a very detailed note on how to define your javascripts in your theme
this might b very useful to u... :)